# The Number of Times a Coin Needs to Be Flipped Until Head Appears

Tags: probability, expectation

I need to find out the number of times a fair coin is needed to flipped, until head appears for the first time.

Now, the options are: 2, 8, 16, and 64.

I don't think it can be calculated. Because every time a coin is flipped, the chance of head appearing is .5 or 50%.

How to calculate this?

Edit: I wrote the question according to the original question I found. The title was written accordingly. Seeing an experienced user's edit on my question, I guess the correct title is: 'The Average Number of Times a Coin Needs to Be Flipped Until Head Appears'.

Comment: The wording of the first sentence seems to imply that by this many coin tosses, we will certainly have had a throw of heads. This is not true - there is no number of coin tosses that can guarantee that we have had a heads. This is because the possibility $TTT\cdots T$ has non-zero probability for as many $T$'s as we like (albeit very small). This also seems to be your opinion on the question. Are you instead looking for the _expected number_ of coin tosses til the first heads? This _can_ be calculated.

Comment: I guess the question is how many times in average a coin needs to flipped until head appears.

Comment: @Royi, yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely correct in saying that the expectation of every single coin flip (read Bernoulli trial) is 1/2. So if the question is what is the probability that it takes 1 single coin flip to get a head, then the answer is 1/2.

What if the question was, "What is the probability that it takes 2 coin flips to get a head?" In this case it would be 1/2 times 1/2, or 1/4.

But the actual question you are asked is slightly more subtle: if you were to repeat the experiment, which is defined as counting the number of coin flips until you get a head, what would be the expected number of tosses (average)? This is a different random variable than the one you are making reference to in your question, i.e. tossing a coin and checking whether it is heads or tails.

The actual computation is straightforward if you know that this is a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution), and you are looking for the expectation (the mean).

If you want to go more into the derivation, check [this video](https://youtu.be/AiQuXEsZCyU).

---

Simulation in R:

```
tosses_til_head <- 0 # An empty vector

for(sim in 1:100000){ # Number of simulations 100,000.
        i <- 1 # Counter
    repeat{
            if(rbinom(1,1,.5) == 0){ # Coin toss (fair) with Boolean (if tails...)
              i <- i + 1} # ... increase the counter by 1.
      else{
            break} # If heads, stop!
    }

tosses_til_head[sim] <- i # Collect the number of tosses before we got H.
}

mean(tosses_til_head) # Average of these 100,000 simulations.

# 2.00416 # Result of one run (not seeded).
```

Comment: Thank you for the video. Statistics is one of those topics I am weakest at. I need to study it more. I understand the logic shown in the video, and according to that the result is 2. What bothers me is that, if we say the whole sentence - 'if we toss a coin, if head does not appear, for sure it will appear at the second time.' So, if the first time tail appears, for the second time, the probability of head-appearing becomes 1! But probability doesn't get changed magically. Can you please point to me what is wrong with this thought process?

Comment: Maybe what someone here named Royi pointed, makes more sense - the 'average' number of times a coin is needed to tossed until head appears is 2.

Comment: Where did you get the sentence "if we toss a coin, if the head does not appear, for sure it will appear at the second time"? If I interpret you correctly, that is a hypothetical sentence you are using to rephrase your question, correct? As you say, the individual coin tosses are independent and identically distributed (in this case as a Bernoulli with probability 1/2) - the probability does not change for each trial.

Comment: What you are calculating is the average number of coin tosses that you would calculate if you were to repeat the experiment (of tossing a coin until you get heads) many, many times. The answer is 2.

Comment: If you happen to be more comfortable coding, I am including a simulation in R for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

geometric distribution $E=\cfrac{1}{p}$. Or by definition of expectation:

$0.5\times 1+0.25\times 2+0.125\times 3+\cdots+0.5^k\times k+\cdots=2$

Answer (score 1):

If we define the random variable $X$ as the number of flips we take until we get our first head, then what we are looking for is the average value of $X$ if we did this over and over again.

You are correct that for each flip, the probability of a head is $0.5$ and similarly the probability of a tails is $0.5$

If we succeed in one flip, then we got a heads on the first flip. If we don't, that means we got a tails, and then we need to essentially "start over" and try again to flip for a heads.

So using expected value, we see that

$$E(X) = 1(.5) + \Bigl(1+E(X)\Bigr)(0.5)$$

Simplifying the above results in $E(X) = 2$

On average the first heads will appear after $2$ flips

Comment: The way I see it, if we can say that at the second time, we will have head for sure, then, at the second toss, the probability of getting head  becomes 1.

Comment: What you are saying would be true if that assumption is true, but it is not. In fact, with a fair coin, we are never guaranteed to get a head on any flip. The possibility of getting 30 tails in a row, for example, exists. Is it likely to happen? No, not at all. But flipping 30 tails in a row has a probability greater than 0. Not by much, though, but it still needs to be considered when we want to find the average number of flips needed to get the first head.

Comment: Your word 'average' draw my attention, and I checked my question. Some experienced user of this site edited my question. But I wrote exactly the way I found the question - 'the number of times a coin needs to be flipped'. I guess the word 'average' was hidden, had to be taken into account, in the original question.